# NextJS Blank Page in Production Build in Docker Only

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, next.js, minify

I am running into an issue that just started yesterday, December 7th 2021 around midday EST. I have a NextJS application deployed in a Docker container. Deploying this app in production mode from inside a container now gives a blank page and a React minify error in the browser console (more details below).

Prior to yesterday I have had no such issue.

This issue is reproducable in a Docker container running both on an AWS EC2 instance and my local machine. There are no errors displayed during local development with `npm run dev` nor when running `npm run build && npm run start` OUTSIDE a docker container. Everything develops, builds and displays fine on my local development environment.

INSIDE the docker container I can run the project fine and load the page with `npm run dev`, but the error seems to be specific to a **production build *inside* this Docker container**. Here is the Dockerfile configuration:

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:14-buster-slim AS deps

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y g++ make cmake python

RUN npm install --frozen-lockfile

# clean up any extra apt packages to save on space
RUN apt-get remove -y g++ make cmake python
RUN apt autoremove -y

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:14-buster-slim AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y g++ make cmake python
RUN npm run build && npm install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline

# clean up any extra apt packages to save on space
RUN apt-get remove -y g++ make cmake python
RUN apt autoremove -y

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:14-buster-slim AS runner
WORKDIR /app

# install cron and curl for the expiringCertificates cron job
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron curl

# make a folder where the cron job can store cookies as text files (see expiringCertificatesCron.sh for reference)
RUN mkdir /app/cron

# Copy cron files to the cron.d directory
COPY --from=builder /app/cron/expiringCertificatesCron /etc/cron.d/expiringCertificatesCron
COPY --from=builder /app/cron/expiringCertificatesCron.sh /app/cron/expiringCertificatesCron.sh

# modify permissions of both cron files to ensure they can be used properly
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/expiringCertificatesCron
RUN chmod +x /app/cron/expiringCertificatesCron.sh

# apply the cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/expiringCertificatesCron

# Create the log file for cron to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

ENV NODE_ENV production

COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/.env.production.local ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["sh", "-c", "cron && node_modules/.bin/next start"]
```

I found this issue when re-building and deploying to production around noon EST, and was surprised to see a blank site, with no title, some of my dark grey css styling, and the following errors in the browser console.

```
main-deb592798b94b511.js:1 Error: Minified React error #200; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Object.t.hydrate (framework-8957c350a55da097.js:1)
    at d.default.createElement.callbacks (main-deb592798b94b511.js:1)
    at xe (main-deb592798b94b511.js:1)
    at main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
    at s (main-deb592798b94b511.js:1)
    at Generator._invoke (main-deb592798b94b511.js:1)
    at Generator.S.forEach.e.<computed> [as next] (main-deb592798b94b511.js:1)
    at L (main-deb592798b94b511.js:1)
    at i (main-deb592798b94b511.js:1)
    at main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
ye @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
s @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
S.forEach.e.<computed> @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
de @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
ve @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
s @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
S.forEach.e.<computed> @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
Promise.then (async)
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
Promise.then (async)
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
Promise.then (async)
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
he @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
t.initNext @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
2870 @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
n @ webpack-cf0a2826ddaf11f3.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
n.O @ webpack-cf0a2826ddaf11f3.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
t @ webpack-cf0a2826ddaf11f3.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1

main-deb592798b94b511.js:1 A client-side exception has occurred, see here for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/client-side-exception-occurred
ye @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
s @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
S.forEach.e.<computed> @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
de @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
ve @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
s @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
S.forEach.e.<computed> @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
Promise.then (async)
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
Promise.then (async)
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
Promise.then (async)
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
he @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
t.initNext @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
2870 @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
n @ webpack-cf0a2826ddaf11f3.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
n.O @ webpack-cf0a2826ddaf11f3.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
t @ webpack-cf0a2826ddaf11f3.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1

main-deb592798b94b511.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cancel rendering route
    at oe (main-deb592798b94b511.js:1)
    at main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xe (main-deb592798b94b511.js:1)
    at main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
oe @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
xe @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
Promise.then (async)
ye @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
s @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
S.forEach.e.<computed> @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
de @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
ve @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
s @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
S.forEach.e.<computed> @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
Promise.then (async)
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
Promise.then (async)
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
Promise.then (async)
L @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
i @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
he @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
t.initNext @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
2870 @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
n @ webpack-cf0a2826ddaf11f3.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
n.O @ webpack-cf0a2826ddaf11f3.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
t @ webpack-cf0a2826ddaf11f3.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-deb592798b94b511.js:1

framework-8957c350a55da097.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #200; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Object.t.hydrate (framework-8957c350a55da097.js:1)
    at d.default.createElement.callbacks (main-deb592798b94b511.js:1)
    at xe (main-deb592798b94b511.js:1)
    at main-deb592798b94b511.js:1
```

I can see all minified JS files downloaded successfully in the `Network` tab, and there are no errors in the server console. Here is the DOM for the blank site (I can see it tried to load my FullPageLoader component but nothing is actually displayed):

[Blank DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4i25.png)

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev",
    "build": "next build --debug",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1021.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "next": "^12.0.2",
    "node-ssh": "^12.0.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.16.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.38.0",
    "serverless-mysql": "^1.5.4",
    "swr": "^0.5.6",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.5",
    "@types/node": "^16.6.1",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
    "@types/react": "17.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.1",
    "@types/ssh2": "^0.5.48",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^27.0.6",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
  },
  "description": "This is a [React.js](https://reactjs.org/) project using the [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) framework to help with routing, rendering, and more. For styling the project includes [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) to add superpowers to our CSS.",
  "main": ".eslintrc.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "<hidden>"
  },
  "keywords": [
    ""
  ],
  "author": "<hidden>",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

NOTE: Rolling back to previous working commits yields the same issue.

The only hint I have to go off of is that in the failing deployment I started seeing the following `postcss` deprecation warning while building the project, before yesterday I did not see this warning:

```
> next build

info  - Loaded env from /app/.env.production.local
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry

info  - Skipping validation of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
postcss-resolve-url: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-resolve-url: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
```

Without any way to properly debug in a production build, I'm not sure what could be causing the minify errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you disable javascript,  do you get anything back in the browser - are you rendering SSR?

In addition i see some invalid html before our body tag from your screenshot `<addoninited..` check which component generates it and remove it

Is it also possible that this is something your browser is injecting, did you try something outside your network, another browser etc?

Comment: I am rendering the entire application client side due to an internal frontend design system library I am using. (I have getInitialProps in _app.tsx). The addoninited component is a result of an internal extension installed on our browsers for my organization. I can verify the site still fails to load on any other device / browser I've tried with the same error. Desktop Edge and Firefox + Mobile/Desktop chrome/Brave

Comment: Looking at your screenshot again, it looks like only the `_error..` chunk is generated, this means the application is trying to load an error page and it fails. I would  install something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino  and log each component success through an `INFO` block , this lets you see what parts of the application succeeded - Given no errors are generated, its just a process of elimination via prod logging.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately/fortunately the issue resolved itself after updating NPM packages on about December 15th. Can only assume one package was causing issues and updating all of them to the latest version fixed the issue.